# How does the browser

Tags: runtime-analysis, functional-programming

I wondering how the browser's JS runtime implements these methods.  I looked on the web and could not find any documentation.

How does something like the V8 runtime actually work to implement these methods into machine code?
 At runtime what does the call stack look like?

1. Function

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
multiply(2, 3);
```

2. Function nested in an associative array at creation time

```js
var MyMath = {
    multiply: function (a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }
};
MyMath.multiply(2, 3);
```

3. Function nested in an associative array, but added after initial construction

```js
var MyMath = {};
MyMath.multiply = function (a, b) {
    return a * b;
};
MyMath.multiply(a, b);
```

4. Function added to an object prototype

```js
var MyMath = function(a) {
    this.a = a;
};
MyMath.prototype.multiply = function(b) {
    return this.a * b;
};
var math = new MyMath(2);
math.multiply(3);
```

5. Function added statically to the Object

```js
var MyMath = function(a) {
    this.a = a;
};
MyMath.multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
};
var math = new MyMath(2);
math.multiply(math.2, 3);
```

6. Function added dynamically in the Object constructor

```js
var MyMath = function(a) {
    this.multiply = function(b) {
        return a * b;
    };
};
var math = new MyMath(2);
math.multiply(3);
```

7. Function dynamically added to an instance of the Object

```js
var MyMath = function(a) {
    this.a = a;
};
var math = new MyMath(2);
math.multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
};
math.multiply(math.a, 3);
```

8. Function added via prototype but references regular function

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
};

var MyMath = function(a) {
    this.a = a;
};
MyMath.prototype.multiply = function(b) {
    return multiply(a, b);
};
var math = new MyMath(2);
math.multiply(3);
```

Comment: Your question seems at once broad and focused on specific Javascript implementations. There must be a lot of literature out there on implementing closures. Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))?